# Simplification of an integral through product manipulation under the integration symbol

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic

Consider an integral of the form

```
Integrate[
f[a*x]
g[c1*z1+c2*z2+c3*z3]
h[e*x]
k[d1*z1+d2*z2+d3*z3]
,{x,0,1}
,{z1,0,2}
,{z2,0,3}
,{z3,0,4}
]
```

Assume that evaluating

```
Integrate[
f[a*x]
h[e*x]
,{x,0,1}]
Integrate[
g[c1*z1+c2*z2+c3*z3]
k[d1*z1+d2*z2+d3*z3]
,{z1,0,2}
,{z2,0,3}
,{z3,0,4}
]
```

is considerably faster than the previous version of it, where `a`, `e`, `di` and `ci` are quantities that make `NumericQ` return `True`.

Is possible to aggroup terms under the integration symbol
by their arguments? I am also interested in a similar simplification for `NIntegrate` or even for hybrid solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this would be simple to achieve automatically (i.e. if you do not know which variables should be "separated", and the corresponding ranges), but you can help MMA along:

```
integrand = f[a*x] g[c1*z1 + c2*z2 + c3*z3] h[e*x] k[d1*z1 + d2*z2 + d3*z3];
split = Times @@@ GatherBy[List @@ integrand, FreeQ[x]]

(* {f[a x] h[e x], g[c1 z1 + c2 z2 + c3 z3] k[d1 z1 + d2 z2 + d3 z3]} *)

Times @@ MapThread[
  Integrate[#1, #2] &,
  {split,
   {Unevaluated@Sequence[{x, 0, 1}], Unevaluated@Sequence[{z1, 0, 2}, {z2, 0, 3}, {z3, 0, 4}]}
  }
]
```

[image: resulting product of integrals]

Comment: Thank you very much. I applied it and I obtained the following improvement: From 0.53159s to 0.057245s.